# Get element value from a POJO List

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, getter, pojo

I have the following POJO.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Notas {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Long delta;
}
```

And I create new indexes in the POJO my adding it.

```
private static final List<Notas> arrayNotas = new ArrayList<>();
arrayNotas.add(new Notas(1,"John",20L));
arrayNotas.add(new Notas(2,"Carol",40L));
arrayNotas.add(new Notas(3,"Peter",30L));
```

How can I have access to any index element once created? How I would be able to access the 3rd element from 3rd row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to the 3rd element,

then go the specific field that you want to access.

in this case. it would be `arrayNotas.get(2).getDelta()`